# Yarn install hangs in offline mode

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Yarn install is hanging in offline mode. Dependencies are in local file system configured through "yarn-offline-mirror" . The server don't have access to the internet.

Commands used to set yarn to offline:

```
yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror /Users/xxx/npm-packages-offline-cache
yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror-pruning true
mv ~/.yarnrc ./

yarn install hangs at "Building fresh packages..." forever.
```

[image]